# Postgres query slows down dramatically when performing addition including column with only null values

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

We've got a query in our DB that's performing a lot slower than we'd like and we've narrowed it down to two columns in a table that, when added to a select calculation, massively increase the query time (30-40s --> 5m30s - 7m). The only interesting feature about these columns is that they currently only contain NULLs. In another environment where these columns do contain values, we do not have this issue.

The query structure is:

```
SELECT (some columns, calculations, etc) 
FROM table_a 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT more columns, calculations, a + ONLY NULLS COLUMN + OTHER ONLY NULLS COLUMN + b 
  FROM view_a) alias_a 
ON table_a.id = alias_a.id 
GROUP BY alias_a.id.
```

The subselect runs fine, and the outer query runs fine *as long as we remove the grouping*. Not certain how to fix this besides inserting dummy data.

explain plan (anonymized as best as possible)

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=10432.09..11510.14 rows=4683 width=484)
Group Key: mc.id
->  Merge Left Join  (cost=10432.09..10456.47 rows=4683 width=251)
Merge Cond: (mc.id = mct.macguffin_child_id)
->  Sort  (cost=439.33..451.04 rows=4683 width=4)
Sort Key: mc.id
->  Seq Scan on macguffin_child mc  (cost=0.00..153.83 rows=4683 width=4)
->  Sort  (cost=9992.76..9992.92 rows=64 width=251)
Sort Key: mct.macguffin_child_id
->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=5221.87..9990.84 rows=64 width=251)
->  Merge Join  (cost=5221.44..9947.83 rows=64 width=211)
Merge Cond: (mp.id = m.phase_id)
Join Filter: (mc_1.macguffin_id = m.id)
->  Nested Loop  (cost=4748.32..10792.40 rows=64 width=223)
->  Nested Loop  (cost=4748.05..10788.94 rows=1 width=223)
->  Index Only Scan using macguffin_phase_pkey on macguffin_phase mp  (cost=0.13..12.18 rows=3 width=4)
->  Materialize  (cost=4747.92..10776.73 rows=1 width=219)
->  Gather  (cost=4747.92..10776.72 rows=1 width=219)
Workers Planned: 1
->  Nested Loop  (cost=3747.92..9776.62 rows=1 width=219)
->  Nested Loop  (cost=3747.49..9625.65 rows=21 width=131)
->  Hash Join  (cost=3747.07..9610.78 rows=21 width=121)
Hash Cond: ((mt.macguffin_id = mc_1.macguffin_id) AND (mct.macguffin_child_id = mc_1.id))
->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=3522.99..8897.48 rows=93186 width=100)
Hash Cond: (mct.macguffin_thing_id = mt.id)
->  Parallel Seq Scan on macguffin_child_thing mct  (cost=0.00..2141.86 rows=93186 width=88)
->  Parallel Hash  (cost=1966.11..1966.11 rows=89511 width=16)
->  Parallel Seq Scan on macguffin_thing mt  (cost=0.00..1966.11 rows=89511 width=16)
->  Hash  (cost=153.83..153.83 rows=4683 width=25)
->  Seq Scan on macguffin_child mc_1  (cost=0.00..153.83 rows=4683 width=25)
->  Index Scan using thing_pkey on thing t  (cost=0.42..0.71 rows=1 width=26)
Index Cond: (id = mt.thing_id)
->  Index Scan using macguffin_thing_calculation_by_date_request_id_composite_key on macguffin_thing_calculation_by_date c  (cost=0.43..7.18 rows=1 width=80)
Index Cond: ((request_id = mc_1.request_id) AND (sku = (t.sku)::text))
->  Index Only Scan using window_start_date_end_date_idx on window w  (cost=0.28..2.83 rows=64 width=8)
Index Cond: ((start_date <= c.date) AND (end_date >= c.date))
->  Sort  (cost=473.12..484.53 rows=4565 width=8)
Sort Key: m.phase_id
->  Seq Scan on macguffin m  (cost=0.00..195.65 rows=4565 width=8)
->  Index Scan using macguffin_thing_calculation_override_thing_id on macguffin_thing_calculation_override mtco  (cost=0.42..0.63 rows=1 width=21)
Index Cond: ((mct.macguffin_thing_id = macguffin_thing_id) AND (c.date = date))
```

The table containing the offending fields

```
-- auto-generated definition
CREATE TABLE macguffin_child_thing
(
    id                      serial  NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT macguffin_child_thing_pkey
            PRIMARY KEY,
    macguffin_child_id integer NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT macguffin_child_thing_macguffin_child_id_fkey
            REFERENCES macguffin_child,
    macguffin_thing_id integer NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT macguffin_child_thing_macguffin_thing_id_fkey
            REFERENCES macguffin_thing,
    thing_field_1       numeric
        CONSTRAINT macguffin_child_thing_thing_field_check
            CHECK (thing_field >= (0)::numeric),
    some_value        numeric,
    thing_field_2       numeric =================================OFFENDING FIELD
        CONSTRAINT macguffin_child_thing_thing_field_2_check
            CHECK (thing_field_2 >= (0)::numeric),
    thing_field_3       numeric =================================OFFENDING FIELD
        CONSTRAINT macguffin_child_thing_thing_field_3_check
            CHECK (thing_field_3 >= (0)::numeric),
    thing_field_4       numeric
        CONSTRAINT macguffin_child_thing_thing_field_4_check
            CHECK (thing_field_4 >= (0)::numeric)
);

ALTER TABLE macguffin_child_thing
    OWNER TO db_owner;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX macguffin_child_thing__unique_idx
    ON macguffin_child_thing (macguffin_child_id, macguffin_thing_id);
```

Comment: You need to post a real query, table definitions (including indexes) , sample data as text - **no images** and the expected output. Also since you concern is performance you need to post the explain plan for the query and a [mre] would be helpful.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: You have something called `view_a`, suggesting that you have a view.  Views are often the root cause of performance issues.

Comment: Added anonymized explain plain, will not be adding real query/table definitions/sample data

Comment: @GordonLinoff that was my first thought but as long as you omit the two fully-null columns (we select other columns from the same table that is part of that view) the query becomes performant again, it's *specifically* the inclusion of these two columns full of nulls